# How to dynamic import js lib/modules/non-components in next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have been using Next.js and know how to use its dynamic import for importing components (named and export) but recently I came across certain npm package that runs on browser only (client-side, requires window) and is quite heavy in size (100kb).

I am having trouble importing them dynamically inside my app.

This is what I get in error while importing such package (which is a non-component package).

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const packageDynamic = dynamic(() => import('npm-package'), {
  ssr: false,
});

... Errors:
Types of property 'default' are incompatible.
Type [package] is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{}>'.
```

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import):

> Next.js supports lazy loading *external libraries with import()* and React components with next/dynamic

`dynamic` is reserver for React components.

You can instead use `import` statement to dynamically import your "non-component" code:

```
const packageDynamic = (await import('npm-package')).default;
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem of not being able to import non-components on the client side. You can't await things on the top level. You'd need to put this in a use-effect or something, which is bad programming because now your imports are severed in two different locations and your effects are more cluttered.